# Handle buttons when switch to new view in monkey c Garmin

Tags: garmin, monkeyc

Hi I have an function to switch to another view:

```
WatchUi.switchToView(new weatherResultView(data), WatchUi.MenuInputDelegate, WatchUi.SLIDE_IMMEDIATE);
```

Inside `weatherResultView` view I need function to handle click on buttons. In the above code I send `WatchUi.MenuInputDelegate` it's delegate to handle click buttons, but I don't know How I can write function to handle click on button.

In `weatherResultView` inside `initialize` function I added: `MenuInputDelegate.initialize();`

And function to handle click on button:

```
function onMenuItem(item as Symbol) as Void {
    switch ( item ) {
        case :item_1: {
            var pos = new weatherPosition();
            pos.findPosition();
            break;
        }
        case :item_2: {
            System.println("item 2");
            break;
        }
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

But this not working.

Answer (score 0):

"Screen level" UI in Monkey C is broken into two parts: views and delegates. Views display the content and get pushed on the view stack, and each is paired with a delegate that handles any necessary input events. There are several classes in the `WatchUi` module that serve as views and several that serve as delegates. You implement your app's UI by subclassing the appropriate view and delegate classes, and pushing instances of them as necessary.

In the code you've given, it looks like you're trying to implement the functionality of a delegate (`onMenuItem()`) in your view subclass, which won't work. You need to create a subclass of `WatchUi.MenuInputDelegate`, override `onMenuItem()` in that delegate subclass, and pass an instance of that subclass as the second parameter to `pushView()`.

Your current `pushView()` call is just passing the name of the delegate class rather than an instance of it, and it looks like you're compiling using the type system, so I'm honestly surprised that `pushView()` line is even compiling at all since the name of a class isn't an instance of the class.